# Alternative to using Marker Interfaces to test for derived generic classes?

Tags: c#, generics, interface, marker-interfaces

I have an application that uses many types of derived classes from a common base class, and several of the derived classes use generics.  The application often needs to iterate through collections of the derived classes and identify specific class types for special processing.

**The problem is how to test for a specific generic derivative of a base class without knowing the type, in a concise and elegant way ( since it is done often in the project ) ?**

The 'is' operator won't work for this:

```
if (item is MyDerivedGenericClass<>)  // Won't compile
```

To work around this problem, I am considering using empty Marker Interfaces to identify the special classes within a collection.  This seems to be the cleanest solution.

A couple of notes:

- This is a closed project, and will not be a commercially distributed library.
- Classes that are tagged by a Marker Interface are being tagged as a permanent unique type, and all derived classes from that type would correctly inherit the Marker.

An example below:

```
public interface MarkerA { }  // Empty Interface
public interface MarkerB { }  // Empty Interface
public interface MarkerC { }  // Empty Interface

public class BaseClass { }

public class DerivedClassA : BaseClass { }
public class DerivedClassB : BaseClass { }
public class DerivedClassC : BaseClass { }

public class DerivedSpecialClass : BaseClass { }

public class DerivedSpecialA : DerivedSpecialClass { }
public class DerivedSpecialB : DerivedSpecialClass { }
public class DerivedSpecialC : DerivedSpecialClass { }

public class DerivedSpecialGenericA<T> : DerivedSpecialClass, MarkerA { }
public class DerivedSpecialGenericB<T> : DerivedSpecialClass, MarkerB { }
public class DerivedSpecialGenericC<T> : DerivedSpecialClass, MarkerC { }


public void ProcessClasses(List<BaseClass> list)
    {
        // Iterate through a list of mixed classes that all derive from BaseClass
        foreach (BaseClass item in list)
        {

            // Ideal approach, but doesn't compile:

            // Try to isolate select class types to do something interesting with
            if ((item is DerivedSpecialA) || (item is DerivedSpecialB) || (item is DerivedSpecialGenericB<>))
            {
                var specialItem = item as DerivedSpecialClass;

                DoSomethingInteresting(specialItem);

                Console.WriteLine(specialItem.Title);
            }


            // Alternative workaround that tests for the Marker instead

            // Try to isolate select class types to do something interesting with
            if ((item is DerivedSpecialA) || (item is DerivedSpecialB ) || (item is MarkerB))
            {
                var specialItem = item as DerivedSpecialClass;

                DoSomethingInteresting(specialItem);

                Console.WriteLine(specialItem.Title);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Does anyone have any better ideas for how to approach this problem ?**

Thanks.

Comment: AntiPattern: "collections of the derived classes and identify specific class types for special processing".    Why don't the classes themselves implement a `Process` method defined in a common interface?

Comment: @spender - Without trying to explain too much, the classes are related to a hierarchical node framework where there are many types of nodes, each derived from a base node.  Some nodes have generic types.  Portions of the main program will iterate through the hierarchy searching for specific types of nodes.  For example, to build a menu that contains some node types, but not others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I need to write code that differs depending on the type of object, and that code is not practical as a virtual method, I use an identifier implemented as a virtual property returning immutable information. This is cleaner, and uses no additional instance storage, although it would be nice to initialize MarkerType via a type parameter.

```
public class BaseClass 
{
    public abstract MarkerType { get; }  
}

public enum MarkerType { A, B, C }
```

Comment: That's a nice approach; it also works well with interfaces, especially if `MarkerType` is a "flags" enum.  In that scenario, it may be possible to expand upon the list of things the "Info" property can report without having to change any existing implementations (it may sometimes be desirable when adding flags to include both a `CanX` and `CannotX` flag if the ability to do `X` could predate the existence of the flag).

Comment: Thanks Frank Hileman for the response.  I have marked this as the accepted answer since it does answer my question, however this isn't ideal for my application.  The application uses MEF plugins, and so the enum designation must be centralized somewhere, whereas Marker interfaces can be assigned in plugins as a distributed designation.  Too bad enums can't be inherited, otherwise this would make a lot of sense.  I think I will stick with Marker Interfaces in this case.

Comment: Hello, you do not need to use an enum; it just has to be an identifier that is immutable (like an interface definition). In your case, static read-only GUIDs would work, or create a centralized distributor of unique ids: a static uint incremented via Interlock every time you acquire a new id. Constant strings with a naming convention that ensures uniqueness (namespace prefix, for example) would also work. Interfaces also work but it is not really the preferred usage for interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

I've been playing around with this problem for a while, and I've come to the conslusion that the code is simply poorly structured from the beginning. If you have base level implementation within `BaseClass`, that should be implemented through the Strategy Pattern using `IBaseClass`. That way, everything has a standardised way of addressing it.

Within your example, you have `.Title` as a property for `specialItem`. I assume this is common for all your MEF export classes. This should therefore be standardised within `IBaseClass`. You can then separate out your contracts using contract names, or via adding `ExportMetaData` attributes to your exports and using Lazy Loading.

**IBaseClass:**

```
/// <summary>
///     Provides mechanisms for working with BaseClasses.
/// </summary>
public interface IBaseClass
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets the title of the MEF Exported class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    ///     The title.
    /// </value>
    string Title { get; }
}
```

**BaseClass:**

```
/// <summary>
///     Acts as a base implementation for all derived classes.
/// </summary>
public abstract class BaseClass : IBaseClass {

    /// <summary>
    ///     Initialises a new instance of the <see cref="BaseClass"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="title">The title.</param>
    protected BaseClass(string title)
    {
        // Set the title.
        Title = title;
    }

    #region Implementation of IBaseClass

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets the title of the MEF Exported class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    ///     The title.
    /// </value>
    public string Title { get; private set; }

    #endregion
}
```

Then derive your classes from there...

**Dervied Classes:**

```
[Export("DerivedClasses", typeof(BaseClass))]
public class DerivedClassA : BaseClass 
{
    public DerivedClassA()
        : this("DerivedClassA")
    {
        /* IoC Friendly Constructor */
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Initialises a new instance of the <see cref="BaseClass"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="title">The title.</param>
    public DerivedClassA(string title) : base(title)
    {
        /* Construction Logic */
    }
}
```

Note here, I've added a contract name to the export. Your special classes widen the functionality of your `BaseClass`, and that functionality should be partioned off into another interface.

**IDerivedSpecialBaseClass:**

```
/// <summary>
///     Provides mechanisms for working with special BaseClasses.
/// </summary>
public interface IDerivedSpecialBaseClass : IBaseClass
{
    string SpecialProperty { get; }
}
```

This interface inherits from `IBaseClass` because it is derived from the same root. Your concrete implementations are the same as above, but implement `IDerivedSpecialBaseClass` rather than just `IBaseClass`.

**DerivedSpecialBaseClass:**

```
/// <summary>
///     Acts as a base implementation for all derived special classes.
/// </summary>
public abstract class DerivedSpecialBaseClass : BaseClass 
{
    protected DerivedSpecialBaseClass()
        : this("DerivedSpecialBaseClass")
    {
        /* IoC Friendly Constructor */
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Initialises a new instance of the <see cref="BaseClass"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="title">The title.</param>
    protected DerivedSpecialBaseClass(string title) : base(title)
    {
        /* Constructor Logic */
    }

    #region Implementation of IDerivedSpecialBaseClass

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets the special property.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    ///     The special property.
    /// </value>
    public abstract string SpecialProperty { get; }

    #endregion
}
```

**Concrete Implementations:**

```
[Export("DerivedSpecialClasses", typeof(DerivedSpecialBaseClass))]
public class DerivedSpecialA : DerivedSpecialBaseClass
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Initialises a new instance of the <see cref="DerivedSpecialA"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public DerivedSpecialA()
        : this("DerivedSpecialA")
    {
        /* IoC Friendly Constructor */
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Initialises a new instance of the <see cref="DerivedSpecialA"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="title">The title.</param>
    public DerivedSpecialA(string title)
        : base(title)
    {
        /* Construction Logic */
    }

    #region Implementation of IDerivedSpecialBaseClass

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets the special property.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    ///     The special property.
    /// </value>
    public override string SpecialProperty
    {
        get { return @"Hello, from DerivedSpecialA"; }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Note the different contract name used, and the different type exported. If you have to use generics, you can add a third interface in the same way.

**Interface:**

```
/// <summary>
///     Provides mechanisms for doing stuff with things.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of things to do stuff with.</typeparam>
public interface IDerivedSpecialBaseClass<T> : IDerivedSpecialBaseClass 
    where T : struct
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Does stuff with things.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="thing">The thing.</param>
    void DoStuffWith(T thing);
}
```

**Primitive**

```
/// <summary>
///     Acts as a base class for all generic special classes.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
public abstract class DerivedGenericBaseClass<T> : DerivedSpecialBaseClass, IDerivedSpecialBaseClass<T>
    where T : struct
{
    #region Implementation of IDerivedGenericBaseClass<T>

    /// <summary>
    ///     Does stuff with things.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="thing">The thing.</param>
    public abstract void DoStuffWith(T thing);

    #endregion
}
```

**Concrete:**

```
[Export("DerivedSpecialGenericClasses", typeof(DerivedGenericBaseClass<>))]
public class DerivedSpecialGenericA<T> : DerivedGenericBaseClass<T>
    where T : struct
{
    #region Overrides of DerivedSpecialBaseClass

    /// <summary>
    ///     Does stuff and things.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="thing">The thing.</param>
    public override void DoStuffWith(T thing)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Doing Stuff and Things with " + thing.GetType().Name);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets the special property.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    ///     The special property.
    /// </value>
    public override string SpecialProperty
    {
        get { return @"Hello, from DerivedSpecialGenericA"; }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Now, the easiest way to handle these within MEF is to create an Adapter class to handle the composition.

**Adapter Class**

```
/// <summary>
///     Adapter class for MEF Imported contracts, deriving from BaseClass.
/// </summary>
public class Classes
{

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the derived classes.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    ///     The derived classes.
    /// </value>
    /// <remarks>
    ///     This list will be populated via MEF.
    /// </remarks>
    [ImportMany("DerivedClasses", typeof(BaseClass))]
    private IEnumerable<IBaseClass> DerivedClasses { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the derived special classes.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    ///     The derived special classes.
    /// </value>
    /// <remarks>
    ///     This list will be populated via MEF.
    /// </remarks>
    [ImportMany("DerivedSpecialClasses", typeof(DerivedSpecialBaseClass))]
    private IEnumerable<IDerivedSpecialBaseClass> DerivedSpecialClasses { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the derived special generic classes.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    ///     The derived special generic classes.
    /// </value>
    /// <remarks>
    ///     This list will be populated via MEF.
    /// </remarks>
    [ImportMany("DerivedSpecialGenericClasses", typeof(DerivedGenericBaseClass<>))]
    private IEnumerable<IDerivedSpecialBaseClass> DerivedSpecialGenericClasses { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Initialises a new instance of the <see cref="Classes"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public Classes()
    {
        // NOTE: This is a generic application catalogue, for demonstration purposes.
        //       It is likely you'd rather use a Directory or Assembly catalogue
        //       instead, to make the application more scalable, in line with the MEF
        //       ideology.
        var catalogue = new ApplicationCatalog();
        var container = new CompositionContainer(catalogue);
        container.ComposeParts(this);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Processes the classes.
    /// </summary>
    public void ProcessClasses()
    {
        foreach (var item in DerivedClasses)
        {
            DoSomethingInteresting(item);
        }

        foreach (var item in DerivedSpecialClasses)
        {
            DoSomethingInteresting(item);
        }

        foreach (var item in DerivedSpecialGenericClasses)
        {
            DoSomethingInteresting(item);
        }
    }

    private void DoSomethingInteresting(IBaseClass specialItem)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Something interesting has been done with: " + specialItem.Title);
    }
}
```

Note that you no-longer need to check which type is which, as they have been split into three separate lists, using the MEF contract names to filter them into the correct list. You should not refer to concrete implementations within your adapter, because you don't know at runtime whether they will exist or not. If they don't, your application will fall over.

Instead, I would suggest adding a `ShouldProcess` flag to the `IBaseClass` interface, and only processing the ones with it set to true.

```
foreach (var item in DerivedSpecialGenericClasses.Where(p => p.ShouldProcess == true))
{
    DoSomethingInteresting(item);
}
```

Something along those lines. Think about separating your concerns. MEF doesn't know what flows through it, so neither will your application. Let that be the focus, and let the plugins tell your application what they need. Implement these checks at the lowest level possible, so that they can be processed wholesale.

Working with MEF can be complicated, when you don't have a full understanding of program flow, design patterns, and scalable architecture. For example, this could be acheived with Lazy Loading instead, with the processing checks added as `ExportMetadata`. It wouldn't add too much overhead, but can be more complicated, if you're not fully swallowing your plugins in one go. When porting over to MEF, from other, less scalable composition engines, it's often needed to rebuild your plugin structure from the ground up; in order to make it fluid, and elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do this:

```
item.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals(typeof(MyDerivedGenericClass<>))
```